# Stop systemd from running user unit for user jenkins

Tags: systemd, jenkins, systemd-unit, systemd-user

I just installed `jenkins` on my pop-os following the [instruction](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/) and install several plugins in `jenkins` when I found that several gnome user unit is started for user `jenkins`

[image: htop screenshot]

I tried restarting my computer, but it doesn't help.

These systemd user unit is still started for user `jenkins`.

How do I stop systemd from running user unit for that user?

Comment: systemd is _supervising_ these things.  But what is _invoking_ them is **not** systemd.  These are Desktop-Bus-activated services.

Comment: @JdeBP OK, but how do I find the program that triggers dbus-activated services and fix that?

Comment: I think this question might has to do with the use of `su -l` in `/etc/init.d/jenkins`.